# Getting PostgreSQL Installation Path From Query

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to find the PostgreSQL installation directory (bin) via query?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid to ask what do you want to do. It sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Ideas are never good or bad, intentions are. I need to know the path of bin directory via query, and then use it in the frontend. Since users can install postgresql in any directory they desire, I cannot hardcode it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply create a table and save the info you want in it as part of your installation procedure.

Comment: If you don't control the installation, why do you care? (You should not care)

Comment: I would suggest that you create the table just like all your other tables for your app, but also ship your customers a script they can run that will detect the bin path and update/insert the appropriate data, including creating the table if that's appropriate

Answer (score 9):

I don't think there is a way to get the path of the Postgres executable.

The only thing that can be retrieved from the system catalogs is the location of the data directory.

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_settings
WHERE name = 'data_directory'
```

This can only be executed by the superuser though.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that. select * from pg_settings  
order by length(setting) desc;

Comment: Is it safe to assume that bin directory will be stored relatively in all installation cases?

Comment: No, not at all. The bin directory will usually be in a completely different path - especially on *nix systems but probably on Windows because the "Program Files" directory is usually not writeable for regular users.

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux system, there will be a /etc/init.d/postgresql script file (possibly with a trailing version number) in which there is a PGENGINE configuration variable which specifies the bin directory, like: PGENGINE=/usr/bin. Other config variables there may also be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the process identifier of the backend (=postgres process) using:

```sql
select pg_backend_pid();
```

How to determine the executable path for a process identifier depends on your OS. On Linux you can just do `realpath /proc/12345/exe`